# Laravel sending form via ajax, and validate using request?

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I am doing ajax which looks like this:

Ajax:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var myform = document.getElementById('#createEntity');
    var fd = new FormData(myform);
    console.log($(this).serialize());
    $.ajax({
        url: "create/add",
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#submit_div').html('<button type="button" class="btn.btn-success"><a href="/profile/entity/edit/'+ data.results +'">Edit</a></button');
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert("Oh no!");
        },
        headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
public function storeEntity(EntityRequestCreate $request)
    {
        $geoloc = new Geoloc;
        $geoloc->lat = $request->input('lat');
        $geoloc->lng = $request->input('lng');
        $geoloc->slug = $request->input('name');
        $geoloc->save();

        $user_id = Auth::id();
        $entity = new Entity;
        $entity->name = $request->input('name');
        $entity->type = $request->input('type');
        $entity->email = $request->input('email');
        $entity->tags = $request->input('tags');
        $entity->_geoloc()->associate($geoloc);
        $entity->save();

        $entity_id = $entity->id;

        $address = new Address;
        $address->building_name = $request->input('building_name');
        $address->address = $request->input('address');
        $address->town = $request->input('town');
        $address->postcode = $request->input('postcode');
        $address->telephone = $request->input('telephone');
        $address->entity_id = $entity_id;
        $address->save();

        $role = User::find($user_id);
        $role->role = "2";
        $role->save();

        DB::table('entity_user')->insert(array('entity_id' =>  $entity_id, 'user_id' => $user_id));

        $result = $geoloc->save();
        $result2 = $entity->save();
        $result3 = $address->save();
        $result4 = $role->save();

        if($result && $result2 && $result3 && $result4) {
            $data = $entity_id;
        }else{
            $data = 'error';
        }
        return redirect('profile/entity');
    }
```

Now the problem is, that I cannot get the data from the form, it is always empty. What is the proper way of sending form throught ajax and dealing with it in controller? I have tried various method like this one above, onclick event on button and nothing seems to work, above code submits and refreshes the page for some reason and it's never successful

Comment: What does your route look like. In either `web.php` or `api.php`?

Comment: Route::post('entity/create/add', 'CreateController@storeEntity');

Comment: Did your change url ajax url to `'/entity/create/add'` to try that?

Comment: yes sorry I should have updated,  it's like this $.ajax({
        url: "/entity/create/add",
        type: 'POST',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: 'JSON',

Comment: Scratch that last comment, deleted.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't add any data to your ajax request. Add the data property to your request object.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "create/add",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: $(this).serialize(),    // <-- Added data property
    success: function(data) {
        $('#submit_div').html('<button type="button" class="btn.btn-success"><a href="/profile/entity/edit/'+ data.results +'">Edit</a></button');
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert("Oh no!");
    },
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Comment: I get: 405 BAD METHOD - The HTTP verb used is not supported. and  Access is denied. any other ajax works fine

Comment: Try putting `POST` as `type`, in capital letters.

Comment: This is sort of what I get: (1/1) MethodNotAllowedHttpException 

in RouteCollection.php (line 251)
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('GET', 'HEAD'))
in RouteCollection.php (line 238)

Comment: however as we seen on the route,it is post

Comment: And if you try running from the `console php artisan route:list`, can you see your endpoint properly set up?

Comment: POST     | entity/create/add                  |                  | App\Http\Controllers\CreateController@storeEntity                      | web,auth     | yeap

Comment: Shouldn't the route for the ajax call be `entity/create/add` then? Or are we already on the `/entity` page? It's always safer to use absolute paths for ajax calls.

Comment: we are already on it, how to I access data I am sending throught controller?

Comment: the thing is in log it says: POST - http://localhost:3000/profile/entity/create why isn't it profile/entity/create/add?

Answer (score 1):

As per jQuery.ajax function's [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), Correct syntax to send the AJAX datax is:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
```

So use `data: $(this).serialize(),` along with code to post data.